# $\lim _{\mathbb{N} \ni N \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) \frac{\sin \left(\left(N+\frac{1}{3}\right) t\right)}{t} d t=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

**Theorem**: Let $ f: \mathbb[-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb{R} $ be differentiable and $ f(0) = 0 $. Show that
$\lim _{\mathbb{N} \ni N \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) \frac{\sin \left(\left(N+\frac{1}{3}\right) t\right)}{t} dt=0$.

**Attempt** ( I didn't really know where to start and where to head myself, so I just wrote whatever came into my mind ):
Denote $ f_n(t) = f(t) \frac{\sin \left(\left(N+\frac{1}{3}\right) t\right)}{t} $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}, t \in [ -\pi ,\pi ] $.
Denote $ g_n = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f_n(t) dt $.   Note that since $ f $ is differentiable then it is continuous on $ [-\pi,\pi] $. Also, $f(t)$ and $ \sin \left(\left(N+\frac{1}{3}\right) t\right) $ are bounded. $ f_n(t) $ is not continuous at $ t=0 $ and note that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) \frac{\sin \left(\left(N+\frac{1}{3}\right) t\right)}{t} dt=  
\int_{-\pi}^{0} f(t) \frac{\sin \left(\left(N+\frac{1}{3}\right) t\right)}{t} dt + \int_{0}^{\pi} f(t) \frac{\sin \left(\left(N+\frac{1}{3}\right) t\right)}{t} dt  $.
Since $ f $ is continuous on a closed interval $ [-\pi,\pi] $ then it is uniformly continuous. Note that $ f_n $ does not converge uniformly. Let $ \epsilon > 0 $, we'll show there exists $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ s.t. for all $ n > N ~~$, $ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) \frac{\sin \left(\left(n+\frac{1}{3}\right) t\right)}{t} dt < \epsilon $

Can you please help? how do I prove the theorem above? I don't know how to start and where should I direct myself too, I feel like the problem's solution is scrambled.. I thought I'd show $ \int_{0}^{\pi} f(t) \frac{\sin \left(\left(N+\frac{1}{3}\right) t\right)}{t} dt $  to be less than some factor of $ \epsilon $ ( this is the main problem, how do I get to show this? ), then say the result will be the same for $ \int_{-\pi}^{0} f(t) \frac{\sin \left(\left(N+\frac{1}{3}\right) t\right)}{t} dt  $ and finally achieve the result.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: $\frac {f(t)\sin (\frac t 3)} t $  and $\frac {f(t)\cos (\frac t 3)} t $ are integrable and the result follows immediately from Riemann Lebesgue Lemma.

Comment: So I use the identities $ sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i} $ , then show the integrals $ \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {f(t) e^{i(N+1/3)t }} t dt, \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {f(t) e^{-i(N+1/3)t }} t  dt$ are Integrable and then use Riemann Lebesgue Lemma? ( The same will hold for the integrals from $ -\pi $ to $ 0 $ )

Comment: If you don't understand Kavi's comment, try using angle-addition to split up the sine term.